# Introduction Javascript - functions, syntax, logic

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I'm attempting to build a rock, paper, scissors game. Here is my code:

```js
var options = ["r", "p", "s"];
    
document.onkeyup = function() {
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keycode).toLowerCase();

    console.log(userGuess);

    var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

    console.log(computerGuess);

    if (userGuess == "r" || userGuess == "p" || userGuess == "s") {
        alert("Chosen Correctly - Good job!");
    } else {
        alert("Please choose r, p, or s");
    }
}
```

when I press r, p, or s my alert doesn't say "Chosen Correctly - Good job!"; instead, the alert is please choose "r", "p", or "s".  HHHmmmm, without this working I can't begin to compare the user guess to the computer guess. Will any fresh set of eyes help me out? Please and thank you.

Comment: @Sam: He's comparing a string to a string, so the strict equal won't change the outcome.

Comment: @squint True thing thanks for point it. But sometimes life is little rare.  I think anyways it's more right if he does strictly equal. The error is that "C" people comment.

Comment: Robert: Welcome to SO! I converted your well-written code sample to a "snippit" so we can run it straight in the question and copy it to answers. You can use that in future questions. (It's available in the button bar.)

Comment: I say to the community who are down-voting because it's simple problem: this is _virtually a perfect question._ It contains a clear problem statement, a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and is relatively well-written. Be cool to the newbies, please! And if you took time to answer, why not up-vote the question? You obviously though it was worth your time...

Comment: @msanford: You make it sound like this question is being heavily downvoted. One user gave it -1. Who cares? If anything, it provides *mild* encouragement for a person to more thoroughly debug before asking.

Comment: @msanford thanks! so in the ask a question page, how do I run snippet instead of just a block of code?

Comment: to all, 
I use the debugger; however, I'm 40 days into coding, still insanely new to this - don't quite understand the error messages in console.  I thought this was a place to learn and grow.

Comment: RobertZobrist: It is a place to learn. Why do you think it's not? Don't let people convince you that you're being abused because of meaningless votes, when in fact you have *multiple* people here who are helping you.

Comment: You're right. I just didnt want the community to think that I'm being lazy. Rather, I'm not very inclined to ask for help.  I only come here when absolutely stumped, after googling, googling, and googling some more.  Again, thanks to all for the swift help.

Comment: @RobertZobrist: No sweat. Those typos can be a drag. Every one of us has been there. I'd just suggest to not take anything for granted, and log every value... and of course using breakpoints as conman124 mentioned below is enormously helpful. Spend an hour or two learning how to step through the code as it executes, and the time spent will be repaid many times over.

Comment: @squint Quite true. I was merely attempting to gently encourage people to encourage OP & newbies in general, and not to risk conflating "badly formed question" with "simple problem", which happens a lot here IMHO. He's brand new to JS, clearly doesn't know how to debug much or he wouldn't have asked. Additionally, I've never understood the idea of bothering to answer a question and not up-voting it. That's all; I'll descend from my soap-box stop high-jacking this question. =)

Comment: @msanford What you have said here is something important. I am relatively new in this community and I can say sometimes you feel the EGO of people which looks over your shoulder at simple questions or even common mistakes we have all made. People who are almost close to insulting the user even seeing from miles away that the intention of the user is learning. I always say that I am here for learning. Also If I try to solve an user issue there is intention of clarify the concepts for myself and improve too. I liked to read veteran people from here talking as it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes:

1. Pass in the `event` so it's available locally.
2. `keyCode` is written in intercaps, (not `keycode`, as you have it); JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Good debugging tip is to `console.dir()` an object you're trying to inspect, that will reveal the correct (and available) property and method names.

(Note, however, that `event` is huge so you'll have a lot to sift through.)

```js
var options = ["r", "p", "s"];
    
document.onkeyup = function(event) {

    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

    console.log(userGuess);

    var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

    console.log(computerGuess);

    if (userGuess == "r" || userGuess == "p" || userGuess == "s") {
        alert("Chosen Correctly - Good job!");
    } else {
        alert("Please choose r, p, or s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a captial C on keyCode.

`var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1):

`event.keycode` should be `event.keyCode`, notice the capital C.  Also, it would probably be better to just use `event.key`, since that is already a string.

What browser are you developing in?  Developer tools can be accessed in most by pressing F12, where you can put a breakpoint to access variables while your program is running.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Chrome - checked console; however, I never noticed that error being referenced.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, hit F12, go to sources, find the file that has you JS, and click on the left side with the numbers to put a breakpoint.  FYI, this is how I figured it out.  I put a breakpoint and saw that `event.keycode` was undefined.  But I noticed that `event.keyCode` *is* defined.  Also, someone else already said this, but you will probably want to add event as an argument to the function: `document.onkeyup=function(event){` since some browsers might not work without that there.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you missed the capital "C" in `keyCode`.

But it also looks to me that you aren't defining `event` anywhere. Using a global `event` object is a bad idea and (thankfully) isn't supported by all browsers. You may also want to use `event.which` rather than `event.keyCode`, which doesn't work consistently for all events.

The start of your event handler should look more like this:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
    ...
```

But you can also use console logging to see what's going on, like this:

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    console.log("event=", event);
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
```

Note that I didn't say `console.log("event=" + event);`

The `+` would cause the event to be output as something like `[object Object]`; with the comma (and any modern browser's developer console, usually accessible with <kbd>F12</kbd>, you'll be able to browse the contents of the object.

Comment: He's using the global `event`, though it's not available in Firefox.

Comment: This confused me too, I didn't know that event gets automatically added.

Comment: thanks for the event.which update, as I'd rather write programs that work everywhere! thanks, man.

Comment: Sure. P.S. And FYI the `console` object isn't supported on IE (last time I checked), don't put leave it in production code (at least not without some sort of hackery). :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have `event` as a paramater to the event handler and it's `event.keyCode` rather than `event.keycode` (w*hich will be undefined*):

```js
var options = ["r", "p", "s"];
    
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var userGuess = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();

    console.log(userGuess);

    var computerGuess = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

    console.log(computerGuess);

    if (userGuess == "r" || userGuess == "p" || userGuess == "s") {
        alert("Chosen Correctly - Good job!");
    } else {
        alert("Please choose r, p, or s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `event.keycode` TO `event.keyCode`